# expressjs: disabling 'x-powered-by' header

Tags: javascript, express

According to `express` docs (and SO), I can use `app.disable('x-powered-by')` to get rid of the `X-Powered-By: Express` header. Docs for `app.disable` are [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.disable), and the table of toggable settings can be seen [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.settings.table).

Here's a simple express server:

```
// src/server.js
import express from 'express'
import logger from 'morgan'
import router from './routes/index.js'

export const createServer = () => {
  const app = express()

  app.disable('x-powered-by')

  app.use(logger('dev'))
  app.use(express.json())
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

  app.use(router)
  return app
}

const app = createServer()

export default app

// src/index.js
import { SERVER_PORT, SERVER_ORIGIN } from './config/index.js'
import app from './server.js'

const port = parseInt(SERVER_PORT, 10)

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.info(`[Server] ${SERVER_ORIGIN}.`)
})

export default server
```

As it can be seen above, I'm using `app.disable('x-powered-by')` straight after app is created. But when i run `curl` the header is still present:

```
$ curl localhost:5000 -v

*   Trying 127.0.0.1:5000...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 16
< ETag: W/"10-/VnJyQBB0+b7i4NY83P42KKVWsM"
< Date: Wed, 22 Apr 2020 12:08:35 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"message":"ok"}
```

I tried changing the capitalization (`app.disable('X-Powered-By')`) but it didn't change anything. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies within `'routes/index.js'`:

```
import Router from 'express'

const router = Router()
```

This doesn't create a router, it creates a new app with its own settings.

Correct would've been:

```
import express from 'express'

const router = express.Router()
```

Answer (score 2):

try this also

```
app.set('x-powered-by', false)
```

It's worked for me.

---

Try also `app.disable('x-powered-by')` after`const app = createServer()`

Comment: Cheers, but it wasn't that. I have to disable it on every `Router()` instance as well, see my answer above.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with `Router()` instances not honoring global `app` settings and reverting to the defaults instead. As it stands, header has to be disabled manually on every `Router()` instance:

```
const router = Router()
router.disable('x-powered-by')
```

Github [issue](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/4246).

Minimal [repo](https://gitlab.com/b00jum/x-powered-by) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. And `Router.disable` doesn't exist for me.

Comment: I've tried to call it on the instance, of course: `TypeError: router.disable is not a function`

Comment: I updated my answer with a repo to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The problem lies within the code you haven't posted before.  Your router is not a router, but a new express app. The import should be `import { Router } from 'express'`.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Post it as an answer and I'll happily accept it. As for the import, I'm using `node` experimental esm support via `"type": "module"` set in `package.json`. If I try to import `Router` the correct way, it yells at me: `SyntaxError: The requested module 'express' does not provide an export named 'Router'`

Comment: I haven't tested the fancy imports before, so my bad. Should then import `express` and use `express.Router()`.

Comment: Turn your comment into an answer, you're right on all accounts here.